# Convert string to Date and compair it to Current date

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello Guys This problem is driving me crazy right now. I have a string in my database called `dueDate` with value `Jan 18, 2018`. I retrieved it and save it in a string in my recyclerAdapter with `String dueDate = transactionTasks.get(position).get_transactiontaskpaydet().toString();`

Now i wanna compare it with the current date and if the due date is after my current date it should display the dueDate with red color.

bellow are my coded.

```
String dueDate = transactionTasks.get(position).get_transactiontaskpaydet().toString();
    Date cdate = new Date();
    Date ddate = new Date(dueDate);

    if(cdate.after(ddate)){
        holder.date.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

This codes work perfectly but the problem is `Date(dueDate);` is deprecated. And when i use another method that uses a `try` and `catch`, i don't get any result.

Below are the codes

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy");
    Date curDate = new Date();
        try {
            Date datedue = format.parse(dueDate);
            if(curDate.after(datedue)) {
                holder.date.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And if I try creating the `Date` outside the `try` block by using `Date duedate = null;` I get an error because its not getting the values inside the `try` block. this is driving me crazy because I shouldn't use deprecated code even if it works perfectly.

All the answers I found didn't work for me. I just need to be able to convert a string to a date so I can compare it with the current date. Thanks Guys

Comment: Use Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); instead

Comment: This is just another "how do I parse a date with an odd syntax" question.  I have linked to a generic Q&A which (among other things) explains how to create a date format that matches your date syntax.  (If that Q&A doesn't work for you, then you have not read it properly!)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with your `SimpleDateFormat`. If your String really is `"Jan 18, 2018"` then you need your `SimpleDateFormat` to match that like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

I made a quick method to test this and it worked fine:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String dueDate = "Jan 18, 2018";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    Date curDate = new Date();
    try {
        Date datedue = format.parse(dueDate);
        if(curDate.after(datedue)) {
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes but what I was missing is  `Locale.ENGLISH` and that was why I kept getting the error. so one it was added to `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);` it worked